# Correct way to sort GridView or its backing ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-6.0, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I've been writing a hobby project in WinUI 3 recently and have run into some trouble.

In my app, I have a `GridView` that's bound in XAML to an `ObservableCollection`, as recommended in the WinUI documentation. This works great, but now I need to be able to sort and filter the items in the `GridView` and it's unclear what the most "correct" or idiomatic way of going about this is.

Googling reveals that WPF has some bits in `CollectionViewSource` to handle this, but those appear to have been removed in WinUI.

Currently the only thing I've founded that works is to remove the XAML binding, change the `ObservableCollection` to a `List`, and then when the user sorts, manually set the `GridView`'s source to `null` followed by setting the source to a sorted version of the `List`. If I'm not mistaken this breaks virtualization in the `GridView` though, so it doesn't seem like what I'm supposed to be doing.

I would greatly appreciate any insight on this.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource?view=winui-3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WinUI, you are supposed to sort the source collection, i.e. the `ObservableCollection<T>`, yourself.

This is a modified (and fairly untested) `BubbleSort` method from [here](https://kiwigis.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-sort-obversablecollection.html) that should come in handy:

```
public static class ObservableCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void BubbleSort<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> o) where T : IComparable
    {
        for (int i = o.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                IComparable o1 = o[j - 1];
                IComparable o2 = o[j];
                if (o1.CompareTo(o2) > 0)
                    o.Move(j - 1, j);
            }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**:

```
someObservableCollection.BubbleSort();
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this UWP method of sorting is fully compatable with WinUI 3 as I haven't tried it.
But the Contoso Orders Example https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-appsample-customers-orders-database has some sample code that changes the Datagrid when the Sorting Event is fired from the Datagrid. Refer to the DataGridHelper in the Views folder.